# Tunning the ECU of a Volkswagen Golf MK6 1.6 TDI DSG

Tags: engine, electrical, maintenance, automatic-transmission, golf

I am a owner of a Volkswagen Golf MK6 1.6 TDI DSG (105HP), and i am a beginner in mechanics, but in computers i am an expert. I stumbled upon those days on some websites that claim to bring you additional 30-40 HP with some ECU tuning techniques (http://www.superchips.co.uk/roadtest/Superchips%20Golf%201.6%20TDI.pdf
), and i am wondering :

1. Can i buy a ECU tunning software from somewhere, some website and install it by myself at home with my laptop connected to the car trough the `VAG-COM cable` ? The reason for this is because i don't have SUPERCHIPS store in my country.

The second question is :

1. How can i connect my car to a device such as a SMARTPHONE that would stay always online and sending me data about LATITUDE and LONGITUDE to my server from 5 to 5 seconds? The part with the SMARTPHONE it is easy to do, especially when programming in `Android` platform.

Thank you.

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: Also, please only ask one question per question.

Comment: RO, and the questions are somewhat related.

Answer (score 1):

For tuning purposes, you have several different options (and probably more):

- [Bully dog](http://www.bullydog.com/product.php?ID=114)
- [Celtic Tuning](http://www.celtictuning.co.uk/manufacturer-tuning-overview/vw-tdi-turbo-diesel-tuning)
- [Malone Tuning](http://www.malonetuning.com/ve-tdi)
- [And many more](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=tuning%20software%20for%20vw%20tdi)

And again, there are plenty of products on the market which will allow you to do what you want to do with the OBD2 system, at least I believe it does considering your real lack of description:

- [Mobile Asset Solutions](http://www.mastrack.com/obd.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=%2B+obd2%2B+gps&utm_campaign=OBD)
- [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FKZYE70)
- [Google Search](http://www.mastrack.com/obd.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=%2B+obd2%2B+gps&utm_campaign=OBD)

It's up to you to decide how/what you want to utilize and how you'd want to tune your vehicle, but there are a huge amount of options out there for you.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to your second question, you can connect to your car with the Wireless Ross-Tech VCDS volkswagen diagnostic system. It is by far the best VW diagnostic tool. The wireless version supports iOS and Android, but isn't exactly cheap. However if you plan on working on your car it's a must.

http://www.ross-tech.com/vcds-mobile/

VWs are very specific vehicles. Help grow the stack exchange community and start the Volkswagen.stackexchange at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75685/volkswage

Answer (score 1):

For logging purposes, the best smartphone app by far is Torque Pro for android.

If you don't know anything about cars, DON'T mess around with fuel/ignition maps. You *are* going to push things too far and end up melting pistons and/or damaging your turbo. I *guarantee* it.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the claims made by a lot of 'tuning' firms are just too much hype. They rely on taking the EGR valve out of circuit, which whilst giving the extra horesepower the vehicle usually gives out excessive nitrides of oxides(NOX). This NOX output is a known killer. Here in the UK somewhere in the region of 5000 people die from or have attributable causes of death from diesel/NOX pollution. You can connect your Android/smartphone to the vehicles ECU with an Elm 327 interface using Bluetooth or WiFi. You need to do your programme using the coding protocols of your vehicle.

Comment: The truth is that you'll only get about 10% extra power from a tuning chip. Any more, and you're going to be causing serious damage to components. Hell, I was promised 20kW(27HP) from a full catback exhaust system and another 20kW from a software update. In the end, both things gave about half of what was promised (but never in writing).